# How to find the index of a matching character vector in a cell array of character vectors

Tags: matlab, char

How do you find the index of a matching character vector in a cell array of character vectors?

For example, in

```
CcharVec={'q','w','e','r','t'};
key1={'r'};
key2={'s'};
```

desired result for `key1` is `4` and some empty object for `key2`. (Note that the elements of `CcharVec` are NOT always scalar.)

`strfind` for example returns a cell array of double arrays where the matching element would be `[1]` and `0x0 double` elsewhere. `find` would not accept such an input. `cell2mat` will lose the position information.

It just escapes me as to how to locate the matching character vector with native functions.

Comment: Does the character vector have to match exactly, or are you looking for substrings. `strfind` is for substrings. I think you might be looking for `strcmp`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Full match. Ty for the tip. Just realized I had always used `find(strcmp(...))` for full match yet today it escapes me.

Comment: For new code, where you have the choice, `string` is generally simpler to use. `Cstrings = string(CcharVec); find(Cstrings == "r")`